# How to make this loop?

Tags: python, loops

How would I loop this?

```
    def start():

     print('welcome to reduce that fraction')

     n=int(input("please enter numerator"))
     m=int(input("please enter denominator"))
     r=2
     while (n%r!=0):
      for y in range(2,10,1):
       a=n%r 
       r=r+1

    while (m%r!=0):
     for x in range(2,10):
      b=m%r
      r=r+1

   print(n/r,"/",m/r)
   print("Goodbye")
  start()
```

I am stuck on how to loop it back to the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: describe what you want to achieve

Comment: Seems like you could just call `start()` again...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the function "start()" to re-run after completing. In that case, here's what I'd do:

```
while True:
    start()
```

This is a boolean while-loop that always holds (Python implicitly parses "while True" as "while True == True"), so the function will keep looping.